# Copy & Paste Performance Counters in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, performance-monitor

It seems the copy & paste function of Performance Monitor on Windows 8 isn't working.  I can't get this simple case to work:

1. Launch Performance Monitor
2. Copy the default % Processor Time counter
   to the clipboard
3. Remove the counter from Performance Monitor
4. Paste
   the clipboard contents back into Performance Monitor

The result should be that the % Processor Time counter should be back but it's not working.  I can even paste the copied counter onto other non-Win8 machines and it works but not on a Win8 machine.  Is anyone else experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I see the same thing in Windows Server 2012.

Here is a work-around:
On the computer you will be copying from:
(I believe steps 1-5 are not necessary on older OSes.)

1. Run mmc
2. File > Add/Remove Snap-in
3. Performance Monitor > Add > OK
4. Console Root > Performance (Local) > Monitoring Tools > Performance Monitor
5. Add the counters that you want
6. File ==> Save As... from the menu

Now, copy that .msc file to the destination computer.
It worked for me.